# Open Graph product.list object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

In my application I've got products and sets of products. 
As I found on Facebook Open Graph documentation, there are two similar to mine `og` types:

Set: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/product.group/

Set element (product): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/product.item/

I tried to describe my application sub-page as one of above `og` types by placing meta tags:

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# product: http://ogp.me/ns/product#">
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxx" /> 
  <meta property="og:type" content="product" /> 
  <meta property="og:url" content="my url" /> 
  <meta property="og:title" content="my title" /> 
  <meta property="og:image" content="my thumb" /> 
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="my sitename" />
  <meta property="product:price:amount" content="my price" />
```

Facebook Open Graph debugger recognizes my url as product. But I do not know can I link product to `product.group`.

I would like to achieve scenario that user may like group of products (`product.group` including many `og` types `product.item`). I've got `url: /list/1` and when someone like/share the list, I want to present it nicely on user timeline.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?  I'm trying to do something very similar...it seems to me it would make sense to be able to share a list or group of items as well as the item.